# Power Point js addin - Unable to insert base 64 svg image into slide

Tags: javascript, powerpoint, office-js, office-addins, powerpoint-addins

Suddenly not able to insert base 64 svg image into slide using office js addin which was possible few week back.
Same thing is working on powerpoint desktop application but not working on powerpoint on web.

Tried changing the code but some library are still not supported in office js.

Comment: A change in behavior is usually a sign of a bug. Also, when something that works on desktop doesn't work on web, that is also usually a bug. Please give the Stack community a couple of days and if you don't get an answer by then, consider creating an issue on the [office-js repo](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/new/choose).